# Double Integral Split Rule

Tags: integration

Suppose we have a function:

$\iint_{-\infty }^{\infty} (ax+by)f_{xy}(x,y) dx dy$

I would like to know what property of the integral rule has been used to rephrase the above equation into like below:

$a \iint_{-\infty }^{\infty} x f_{xy}(x,y) dxdy + b \iint_{-\infty }^{\infty}y f_{xy} (x,,y) dxdy$

Thank you for your help.

Comment: that's just linearity of integrals.

Comment: I.e. if $u,v$ are two functions, and $I$ is the integral, then $I(au+bv)=aI(u)+bI(v).$ Incidentally, why do you write $f_{xy}$ and not simply $f?$

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is basic and was already answered in the first comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linearity of the integral operator, i.e.

$$I((ax+by)f)=I(axf+byf)=I(axf)+I(byf)=aI(xf)+bI(yf)$$